# Sharing custom flash player on Google Plus

Tags: google-plus, meta-tags, flash

Is there any way to share custom flash player on google plus. Like we share custom flash player on facebook,twitter using og tags and twitter cards.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure, but as far as I know google hasn't implemented a way of using you own flash player in google plus. They have their own player and I don't know if they want us to use our own.